# How to get year interval between two date in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want the year intervals like this

fromdate = 15-09-2019, todate=21-09-2021

15-09-2019 - 31-12-2019 //for the year 2019

01-01-2020 - 31-12-2020 //for the year 2020

01-01-2021 - 21-12-2021 //for the year 2021

so that i can able to get data from those intervals

[In this table i have values only for 2021 but not for 2019 and 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIeUO.png) 
If any there is no data in the range of 2019 and 2020.It should prdouce 0 for the parameter Traincount and tonnage.

Comment: What is the desired result for these operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a brute force approach to getting a yearly summary, which is to break the data out by days and then aggregate:

```
select min(dte), max(dte)
from generate_series('2019-09-15'::date, '2021-09-21'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte)
group by date_trunc('year', dte);
```

However, more efficient method would avoid aggregation:

```
select greatest(gs.dte, v.fromdate),
       least(gs.dte + interval '1 year - 1 day', v.todate)
from (values ('2019-09-15'::date, '2021-09-21'::date)) v(fromdate, todate) cross join lateral
     generate_series(date_trunc('year', v.fromdate), date_trunc('year', v.todate), interval '1 year') gs(dte);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=162c014b79280fe91c7ab7e48804613c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff .This query Really worked.Can you please explain me in elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Simply subtract them:

```
SELECT ('2015-01-12'::date - '2015-01-01'::date) AS days;
```

The result:

```
 days
------
   11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select extract('year' from now()) - extract('year' from now());
```